# not able to remove tags that "xsi:nil" in them via xslt

Tags: xslt, xml-nil

I have following xml which contains several xml tags with xsi:nil="true". These are tags that are basically null. I am not able to use/find any sxlt transformer to remove these tags from the xml and obtain the rest of the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p849:retrieveAllValues xmlns:p849="http://package.de.bc.a">
    <retrieveAllValues>
        <messages xsi:nil="true" />
        <existingValues>
            <Values>
                <value1> 10.00</value1>
                <value2>123456</value2>
                <value3>1234</value3>
                <value4 xsi:nil="true" />
                <value5 />
            </Values>
        </existingValues>
        <otherValues xsi:nil="true" />
        <recValues xsi:nil="true" />
    </retrieveAllValues>
</p849:retrieveAllValues>
```

Comment: do you want to remove all elements with attribute `xsi:nil="true"` from document?

Comment: Yes. I want all the tags that have xsi:nil="true" in them to be removed. I tried several of the existing xslts present on this and other websites but none worked for me. All of them gave me the same error which is "[Fatal Error] file2.xml:5:30: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:nil" associated with an element type "messages" is not bound."

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible in XSLT at all, I've added an answer with an [alternative approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14877916/592139) that seems to do the right thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of error you get

> [Fatal Error] file2.xml:5:30: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:nil" associated with an element type "messages" is not bound.

is absence of prefix named "xsi" declared, you should specify it in root element such as:

```
<p849:retrieveAllValues xmlns:p849="http://package.de.bc.a"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<retrieveAllValues>
    <messages xsi:nil="true" />
       // other code...
```

### update

If you could not change xml document you're receiving from webservice, you could try next approach(if this approach is acceptable for you):

1. Change your `xslt` document to process xml documents without specifying element prefixes
2. Set property `namespaceAware` of [`DocumentBuilderFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29) to false

After this yout transformer shouldn't complain

Comment: I see the problem now. The xml input to one mf my transformers does not have the schema in it. But I really do not see how can I manipulate the schema here (to add - xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in it) so that before it reaches the transformer, the missing schema gets added to it.

Comment: @Anand, what do not you see? Sorry, I could not get what you exactly mean. Did you try to add this xmlns declaration? Do you still have the same error?

Comment: Your solution is correct. But for me it is a different problem. The xml that I am transforming using an xslt is coming out of a web service call. The response of the service goes to the xslt, which sees the schema as missing and rightly complains. So now I am wondering if and how can i force the service response not to omit this required schema.

Comment: @Anand, are you using java?

Comment: Would there be a way to do a manipulation in the xslt directly ? I really did not understand the option #1 where you said "Change your xslt document to process xml documents without specifying element prefixes". Would there be an example to refer ?

Comment: @Anand, `<xsl:template match="element">` instead of `<xsl:template match="prefix:element">`, etc.

Comment: Well .. No matter what i try from xslt side, I am always getting an error -- "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'xsi'" in my input xml. So it is not even going to the xslt to see what kind of processing is inside that.

Comment: namespaceAware is by default false. just wanted to add that.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is going to be possible in XSLT - because of the missing namespace declarations you have to parse the XML file with a non-namespace-aware parser, but all the XSLT processors I've tried don't get on well with such documents, they must rely on some information that is only present when parsing with namespace awareness enabled, even if the document in question doesn't actually contain any namespaced nodes.

So you'll have to approach it a different way, for example by traversing the DOM tree yourself.  Since you say you're working in Java, here's an example using Java DOM APIs (the example runs as-is in the [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) console, or wrap it up in a proper class definition and add whatever exception handling is required to run it as Java)

```java
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.*;

public void stripNils(Node n) {
  if(n instanceof Element &&
      "true".equals(((Element)n).getAttribute("xsi:nil"))) {
    // element is xsi:nil - strip it out
    n.getParentNode().removeChild(n);
  } else {
    // we're keeping this node, process its children (if any) recursively
    NodeList children = n.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
      stripNils(children.item(i));
    }
  }
}

// load the document (NB DBF is non-namespace-aware by default)
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDoc = db.parse(new File("input.xml"));

stripNils(xmlDoc);

// write out the modified document, in this example to stdout
LSSerializer ser =
  ((DOMImplementationLS)xmlDoc.getImplementation()).createLSSerializer();
LSOutput out =
  ((DOMImplementationLS)xmlDoc.getImplementation()).createLSOutput();
out.setByteStream(System.out);
ser.write(xmlDoc, out);
```

On your original example XML this produces the correct result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p849:retrieveAllValues xmlns:p849="http://package.de.bc.a">
    <retrieveAllValues>

        <existingValues>
            <Values>
                <value1> 10.00</value1>
                <value2>123456</value2>
                <value3>1234</value3>

                <value5/>
            </Values>
        </existingValues>


    </retrieveAllValues>
</p849:retrieveAllValues>
```

The empty lines are not actually empty, they contain the whitespace text nodes either side of the removed elements, as only the elements themselves are being removed here.